# What's the difference between bonus and status miles?

Tags: loyalty-programs, turkish-airlines

Turkish Airlines offers me on their website to convert my bonus Miles into status Miles. What miles are applied to get a ticket as a reward?

Comment: They should be equal for ticket booking; the difference is probably that bonus miles _can't_ make you Silver or Gold member, no natter how many, whereas status miles _can_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status miles count towards earning status, and also earn you redeemable miles. Bonus miles do not count towards status, they are only redeemable. So say you fly 1000 miles: there might be a "double miles" offer but typically the second 1000 miles is just bonus miles, not status miles. Miles from credit cards or non-flying partners (eg rental cars) are usually only bonus miles.

If you are not going to be close to a status level, you should not take this deal. I actually find the [Turkish miles levels](https://p.turkishairlines.com/en-ca/miles-and-smiles/how-does-it-work/benefits-and-privileges/index.html) to be confusing but I think you need 17,000 miles to make Classic Plus. If you're at 16,000 and don't plan to fly more, and you think the benefits of Classic Plus (use the business class checkin lines and business lounges on domestic lights, for example) are worthwhile, then giving up some of the redeemable miles (eg exchanging 5000 bonus miles for 1000 status miles) would be worth it to you. 1 to 1 would be even better but I doubt they're offering that. However if you're at 5,000, chances are it won't be worth it.

Comment: So to redeem a ticket, what miles are used?

Comment: redeemable miles. Both bonus and stats are redeemable. That's why giving up a lot of bonus miles to get a small number of status miles could be bad: you're lowering your redeemable miles. But it could be worth it if you're effectively redeeming for the benefits that status brings.